# Condition for a dominant eigenvector to be everywhere nonzero

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a condition under which all elements of a dominant eigenvector of a square matrix are nonzero? I'm familiar with the Perron-Frobenius theorem for nonnegative matrices that are irreducible. I'm wondering whether there is a similar theorem about dominant eigenvectors of matrices that may not be nonnegative. Specifically, I presume that a square matrix that may have negative elements but is not block triangular should have a dominant eigenvector that is everywhere nonzero, but I'm not sure whether this is correct? Many thanks!

Comment: Consider the matrix with rows {8,2,-8}, {10,0,-8},{-1,1,2}. Eigenvalues are $10,2,-2.$ Eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalue have the third coordinate $0.$

Comment: Thanks! So my presumption was incorrect. I wonder whether there are other conditions that would ensure  that the dominant eigenvector is nonzero.